# Getting money transferred from abroad from my parents, would I get taxed?

Tags: united-kingdom, international, foreign-income

I'm originally from Japan but living in the UK permanently on spouse visa now. My parents transfer money from Japan to my British bank every now and then like £8000 every year as a gift, does this count as a foreign income?
I know that UK doesn't tax on gift money unless the giver dies within seven years, but my parents are in Japan so I assume it doesn't apply to me?
I just wanted to make sure that any money that my parents are sending to me is just recognised as gift money and not foreign income somehow.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. There's no automatic way money transfers are taxed, so you won't have to explain yourself to anyone.

And no tax is actually due because there's no gift tax in the UK. As you say there might be UK tax if your parents lived in the UK and died within 7 years, but as they live in Japan there won't be (I can't say anything about gift taxes/inheritance taxes in Japan).

Even if they did live in the UK there might well be exemptions in the case you describe ("regular gifts out of income"), but as you don't need them I won't bother going into that.